# How to learn if i am compiling for 32bit or 64bit and how to change that?

Tags: c++

So i was having trouble with reading memory. I was successful reading values that has short addresses like `0x5CD38994` but when i try longer addresses like `0x2840C6C68D8` i only get 0. Some people said that i should compile my code for 64bit. But i don't know if i am compiling it for 32bit or 64bit. How to learn that and is it changed on my IDE or is it about compiler? I am using Eclipse IDE and GCC compiler. What should i do to compile my code for 64bit?

That works:

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x5CD38994, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0);
```

That does not:

```
ReadProcessMemory(pHandle, (LPVOID)0x2840C6C68D8, &my_value, sizeof(my_value),0);
```

Comment: You try to read memory from some process which typically is only used if you write debuggers or other special stuff. But you don't know how to compile for 32 or 64 bit? Can you tell us what you are doing? And using gcc and win api is also a bit "special"...

Comment: YOU decide if you compile for 32bit or 64bit, based on what kind of compiler you are using, and how you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

0x2840C6C68D8 is a 64 bit address.  You cannot use ReadProcessMemory() from a 32bit process and try to read a 64bit address, you must compile for x64.

To compile for x64 on GCC use `gcc -m64`, you should be able to add that to your compiler/linker flags somewhere in the settings for your IDE

Comment: *"use `gcc -m64`"* Some MinGW distributions (at least MSYS2, I think) provide separate compiler installations for x32 and x64. In this case, you only need to install the right compiler, and no flags.